# Return only group in regex find all

Tags: python, regex

I have a long text and want to match all occurances of "the rate is (\d+\.\d)%" but want to only return the group (\d+\.d) as a list of matched strings. How can I do that?

I can't just match the group, because it occurs in other context as well.

Example

```
"I like how the rate is 6.7%. Now the rate is 11.4% profits were down by 5.6%"
```

In this case I would need

```
[6.7, 11.4]
```

---

I see, I thought that findall return the whole string matched, not the group. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, just group the part you want returned:

```
r'the rate is (\d+\.d)%'
```

so provide enough context to only match what you want returned, and use a capturing group. Then use the `.findall()` method, which will only include the matched capturing groups:

```
>>> re.findall(r'the rate is (\d+\.\d)%', "I like how the rate is 6.7%. Now the rate is 11.4% profits were down by 5.6%")
['6.7', '11.4']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [94]: s="I like how the rate is 6.7%. Now the rate is 11.4% profits were down
 by 5.6%"

In [95]: re.findall(r'the rate is (\d+\.\d)%', s)
Out[95]: ['6.7', '11.4']
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using `re.findall()`.

See [7.2. re — Regular expression operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)